# Remove-Item didn't work inside Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to query SQL Server, exported result to CSV file, upload files to Blob and then delete file on `C:\` drive.

But when executing this script,

```
Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*
```

didn't delete any file or didn't give any error.

If I tried to execute the command

```
Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*
```

from PowerShell as a single command, it worked.

```
$datetimeToString = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d-%A-%H-%M-%S"
$JobPath = "C:\result\Job-$datetimeToString.csv"

$QueryJob = "select * from HPCScheduler.dbo.Job"


$accountKey = "my-key"
$dest = "my-container"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance MYSQLSERVER -Database HPCScheduler -Query $QueryJob | Export-CSV $JobPath


$azCopyPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
Set-Location $azCopyPath 

.\AzCopy.exe /Source:$JobPath /Dest:$dest/Job-$datetimeToString.csv /destkey:$accountKey /Y

Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*
```

@Problem solved by using another Set-Location to move to different directory.
For example

```
Set-Location -Path C:\result
Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*
```

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose your problem. `Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*` should only quietly skip deletion of files if they either have no filename extension or have the Hidden attribute.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding one more Set-Location to change the working directory back.

Comment: That is strange, given that `Remove-Item –path C:\result\*.*` should in no way depend on what the current location is. If you can reproduce the problem with an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I encourage you to delete this question, ask a new one with the MCVE, and - if you have a reliable workaround - self-answer it.